# Display minus sign on the right side of the number

Tags: php, numbers, format

I have a mixture of numbers, positive and negative numbers. For example:

```
$array = array(4, -79, 5.56, -5.000.533, 96);
```

Now I want to display them all, but I want to show minus sign `-` on the right side of the number.

So the result I am looking for is:

```
4 
79- 
5.56 
5.000.533- 
96
```

How do I do that in php ?

Comment: No idea why you would want to do this but maybe try this: `abs($neg_number).'-';`.

Comment: Mr Down voter can you explain the reason for down voting ? :/

Comment: No down vote from me - was just trying to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to be formatting a lot of numbers it would be best to use the [NumberFormatter](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class, that way it deals with your positive and negative numbers in the way you want (assuming you don't want to display a *+*).

Using the array you've added:

```
$onFormatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$onFormatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::NEGATIVE_PREFIX, "");
$onFormatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::NEGATIVE_SUFFIX, "-");

$array = array(4, -79, 5.56, -5000533, 96);

foreach($array as $f) {
    echo $onFormatter->format($f) . "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
4
79-
5.56
5,000,533-
96
```

Comment: This is great! But how can I include NumberFormatter class?

Comment: It's part of PHP's standard stack since 5.3

Comment: If you're on a Windows local stack you may need to add the `Intl` extension - just uncomment `extension=php_intl.dll` in php.ini and reboot Apache

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be something like this. Thanks again. I upvoted you (best answer).

Comment: Thanky :)      [just something to hit the minimum character limit here]

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try now ::)

Comment: Thank you I have used your solution and it worked great :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the negativity of the value then you can achieve the same result using CSS:

```
$number = -4126;
echo '<span style="display: inline-block; direction: rtl;">'.$number.'</span>';
```

Result at broswer:

```
4126-
```

**EDIT 1** (edit on comments):

If you only want to show it's value you can do the following:

```
echo $number > 0 ? $number : abs($number).'-';
```

**EDIT 2** (for the updated question):

```
$array = array(4, -79, 5.56, '-5000.533', 96);

foreach($array as $number) {
    echo $number > 0 ? $number.'<br />' : abs($number).'-<br />';
}
```

**Result**

```
4
79-
5.56
5000.533-
96
```

Comment: This won't work as It will need to be exported to CSV later, but thanks anyway. I have updated the question

Comment: Then you can only reverse if it's negative like the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful

Comment: Please try @CD001 solution. I think it suits you better.